# Quick Release mounts for VESA/monitor mounting?

Tags: multiple-monitors, connector, vesa

What I've found out so far online:

- I know about the various hole patterns, monitors tend to be 75x75 or 100x100mm square patterns.  TVs that you might use for a larger monitor might be 200x100.
- As far as screw sizes, the 75x75, 100x100 and 200x100 tend to use metric "M4" screws at least 10mm long, 4mm outer diameter, course 0.7 thread pitch, etc.
- And for larger TVs, I've seen some vendor specific quick release systems.

But is there such a thing as a "quick release VESA adapter" for monitors?

Here's the scenario:

- When using standard VESA screw mounting, you've got to hold a monitor in mid air, quite precisely, while another person tries to insert 4 rather finicky screws.
- If a monitor connection point is up high or in some other awkward-to-access spot, this gets really difficult, even for a 3 person team.
- Some vendors let you secure the arm to the monitor while it's on a table, then pop the monitor in place, but is very vendor specific.

What would be easier, if it exists at all, would be:
* Screw in half of some "adapter" into the monitor mounting point or end of the arm, with a standard VESA hole pattern.
* Screw the second half of this "adapter" into the monitor, while it's on a table.
* Then lift up the monitor to the mount point and "click-in" or "hook on" or otherwise engage the two halves of the adapter.

I'm NOT looking for "shopping advice", I'm asking if such a things exist at all?  And if so, what they might be called?

And if there aren't any "quick release" monitor standards, then= what do other folks do in these situations?  This must come up?  Does everybody just settle for one vendor for their entire system / company?

And let's say you didn't mind buying from a subset of vendors, do any of the modular mounting systems interoperate with each others parts?  Can I get "rails" from one vendor" and "arms" from another?

Moderators: I realize superuser is often about OS issues, but VESA is a pretty important standard for physically mounting peripherals.  I'd think most power users would want multiple monitors these days, so options for configuring that would seem on-topic.  And I don't see this information discussed, in this way, on other sites.  Google searches keep bringing back vendor pages, etc, not useful information.

Answer (score 1):

There are several such adapters exactly.

E.g. the Ergotron Quick Release LCD Bracket http://goo.gl/JvMHLK

Answer (score 0):

I... have never had trouble finding a wall mount that doesn't come in two pieces that snap together. I find it strange that you are; try your local Radio Shack or whatnot.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio.  You mentioned wall mounts, were these for TVs?  Or monitors?  Although they're both "VESA", the TV mounts are the larger VESA variants.  In my case, one of the VESA mounts is already in place, and doesn't have the snap mount.  The snap parts you've seen from different vendors, did they seem like they would interoperate with each other?

Comment: They had 75, 100, and 200 holes, so could mount either. From different vendors, no; they always came as both pieces together, but were different from vendor to vendor.

Comment: After trying several mounts, the problem with wall mounts is they expect to go into a well, so the wall-side doesn't obey the VESA standard.